# Is there a way to make a "reusable snapshot" of a program?

Tags: c++, snapshot

Here's the situation: I am working on a relatively big C++ program (in Linux). This program can be separated in two parts. Part A is just a bunch of precomputations based in some data that remains the same over time that builds a pretty complex and big data structure. The problem is that part A takes too much time (around a minute), and you can assume that it cannot be significantly optimized further. Part B, which goes right after part A, is basically some queries on the data loaded in part A.

So, here's what I want to do: since the data structure built in part A is always the same, wouldn't it be nice to have a "snapshot" of it, and so, every time you load the program you can just retrieve the data from the snapshot very quickly and just jump right to B?

And here's the question: Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You could compute it once, store it to a file, and then just read in that file into the data structure on program startup.

Comment: .so on linux or .dll on windows?

Comment: @NathanOliver the purpose of this is precisely to avoid what you are saying. The structure is too big and complex, full of pointers and stuff, and you want to retrieve it very quickly

Comment: @Aconcagua Linux

Comment: of course there is a way to do that and if you have a huge precomputing step then of course you should safe your data after this step, so you can repeatedly work on B without rerunning the same A all the time. However, there is no automagic way to do that. Much more details on what is A and what is B would be required to answer this in a meaningful way

Comment: @idclev463035818 I'm actually looking for the most automagic way possible :-(

Comment: "the most automagic way possible" as there is no automagic way the choice is simple :P

Comment: **Pointers???** – these you'll have to set up newly again and again when loading the data. No way around. There's no guarantee that the data will get loaded at the same location it was before in another programme run. At best you could have a great struct and store offsets inside that struct. Then when retrieving a pointer, you'd have to add the offset to the base pointer of the struct...

Comment: honestly what I read between the lines is that you have a design problem. If your cannot store the data to a file after A, then that is your problem that you should fix imho

Comment: Is step A "load the data from a human-readable file"? or similar

Comment: As others have said, I would recommend serializing the structure from A into a file and deserializing it in B.

Comment: Various programs have tried to do things like dumping and reloading the application's entire memory space in the past, with varying degrees of success, but it's always *very* fragile.  For an example, see Visual C++ PCH files.  It's much safer to dump an entire allocation heap than the entire program (and then your structure can only contain based pointers within the heap, never function pointers or vtables).

Comment: Alternative solution: run the program in a VM, which you can suspend, take snapshots etc.

Answer (score 6):

What you describe is basically "checkpointing" in HPC: you designate a chunk of memory that can be restored quickly if the program is restarted, without investing significant time in saving/loading this data.

There are many libraries or checkpointing out there, but I have used [Ken](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~tpkelly/Ken/) in the past to great effect.
What this library does is create a virtual memory mapping **at a fixed memory location**, together with a mechanism for automatically capturing this memory to disk and reloading it.

When the program is restarted, you simply map the memory again and check if it was initialized or not.
Thus, your startup time is reduced to virtually nothing (the time to memory map the file and load some chunks from disk as you need them).

You did not present any code so I cannot give you concrete advice, but you will need to ensure that all memory allocations for the expensive piece are made inside of Ken-managed memory, for example by implementing your own memory allocator backed by the Ken-managed memory, by passing a custom allocator to all STL data structures, or simply convincing your memory management library of choice to allocate memory in the Ken memory. For an example of the last option, see [jemalloc](http://jemalloc.net/jemalloc.3.html)'s `arena.create` and `thread.arena` options.

Answer (score 2):

For an automagic solution that doesn't require code you can take a look at [CRIU](https://criu.org/Main_Page) (Checkpoint/Restore In Userspace) which allows you to freeze a running process and checkpoint its state to disk. To then restore the process and run it exactly as it was during the time of the freeze.

Answer (score 0):

If you control all the allocations used in this data-structure, there might be a reasonable way.

You start with the bytes of your "A.saved" file. Rather than having pointers, you instead have offsets from the start of the file.

```
unsigned char * start; // !! global pointer

template <typename T>
class offset_ptr {
    std::size_t offset;
public:
    offset_ptr(std::size_t offset) : offset(offset) {}
    offset_ptr(T* ptr) : offset(pointer - start) {}

    T& operator*() const { return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(start + offset); }
    T& operator->() const { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(start + offset); }
};
```

Comment: This is made easier if his compiler has support for "based pointers".  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/based-pointers-cpp?view=vs-2019